# Find Duplicate on userform after textboxes updates

Tags: excel, vba

Morning All

i was wondering if anybody could help me with my below code. i have an user form with many controls however on my userform Testbox1 has First Name, textbox2 has second name and textbox3 their DOB is there anyway that user will be informed once thier put the details on to Textbox1, textbox 2 and finally textbox 3 and message box to say person already exit on the records and inform user what cell number it is located on the sheet.

Name it is in column B, second name in Column C and DOB is in column D

```
Private Sub TextBox3_AfterUpdate()
    If Application.CountIf(Range("B:B", "C:C", "D:D"), TextBox1, 
     TextBox2, TextBox3) > 0 Then
   MsgBox "Person Already Exists", vbCritical, "Duplicate Found"
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to use `COUNTIFS` not `COUNTIF`

Comment: Hi Nathan thanks but i get an error on the line " (Range " saying compile error wrong number or argument

Comment: COUNTIFS will be range1,criteria1,range2,criteria2,range3,criteria3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As VBA considers datevalues in US or "yyyy/mm/dd" date formats, if the system date/ excel date format is UK then only year could be compared like in the code below. Or refer [FormatForLocale function](https://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2020/10/internationalise-dates-in-vba.html) for date format conversion in VBA

```
Private Sub TextBox3_AfterUpdate()

Dim FullStr As String
Dim FltArrStr As String, lRow As Long, FltArr, arr, yr

If TextBox3.Value = "" Then
    yr = ""
Else
    yr = Year(TextBox3.Value)
End If

FullStr = TextBox1.Value & " " & TextBox2.Value & yr
lRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If yr = "" Then
    arr = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(Evaluate( _
        "IFERROR($B1:$B" & lRow & "&"" """ & _
        "&$C1:$C" & lRow & _
        ","""")"), 0, 1))
Else
    arr = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(Evaluate( _
        "IFERROR($B1:$B" & lRow & "&"" """ & _
        "&$C1:$C" & lRow & _
        "&YEAR($D1:$D" & lRow & "),"""")"), 0, 1))
End If

FltArr = Filter(arr, FullStr, True, vbTextCompare)
FltArrStr = Join(FltArr, vbCrLf)
If UBound(FltArr) >= 0 Then MsgBox "Duplicate Names Found" & _
        vbCrLf & vbCrLf & FltArrStr, vbCritical, "Duplicate Found"
End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT as per comments below** If DOB need not be considered then, with countifs (as suggested by @Nathan_Sav in the comments on the question), alert message box will appear once first name and last name are entered and duplicate is found with count > 0.

```
Private Sub TextBox2_AfterUpdate()
Dim lRow As Long, MatchRow As Long
lRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If TextBox1.Value <> "" And TextBox2.Value <> "" And _
    WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("B2:B" & lRow), TextBox1.Value, _
    Range("C2:C" & lRow), TextBox2.Value) > 0 Then
MatchRow = Evaluate("MATCH(""" & TextBox1.Value & TextBox2.Value & """," & _
                    ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B" & lRow).Address & "&" & _
                    ActiveSheet.Range("C1:C" & lRow).Address & ",0)")

MsgBox "Name " & TextBox1.Value & " " & TextBox2.Value & " Already Exists" & vbCrLf & _
        "Duplicate Found at Row " & MatchRow, _
        vbCritical, _
        "Duplicate Found"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Naresh Thank you but i get an error variable not defined on 'lRow', 'arr', 'FltArr', 'FltArrStr' and sorry all dates are in UK format as DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: when i pasted your second suggestion in to my userform(myForm)

Comment: Add this at the top after Private Sub statement `Dim FltArrStr as String, lRow as Long, FltArr, arr`

Comment: Hi Naresh it worked however if i clear the textbox3 for whatever reason i get an error "Type Mismatch" Run time error 13

Comment: sorry on the line 'FullStr = TextBox1.Value & " " & TextBox2.Value & Year(TextBox3.Value)'

Comment: Editing the answer assuming that the full record including DOB needs to be compared. If duplicates need to be  shown for first and last name (excluding DOB) `Private Sub TextBox3_AfterUpdate()` could be replaced with `Private Sub TextBox2_AfterUpdate()`

Comment: Hi Naresh it worked however when duplicate is found and when i clear the textbox 1 first and then clear textbox2 and click on the textbox 2 i get an message box  poops up with the all names on the messagebox

Comment: So, in that case (if DOB need not be compared), countifs is enough. Editing accordingly.

Comment: Good Morning Naresh thank you your 3rd suggestion worked. just quick question how do i include the cell number of the duplicate found on text box?

Comment: and sorry how do i also include the person name on the message box when duplicate found on your last 3rd suggestion?